# 1 day per week or One day per week

Tags: resume

I am currently writing my CV and I was wondering if it's better to write 1 day per week or One day per week. What's your opinion?

Best

Comment: this is really not the sort of question we typically answer on this site, but that being said, stay away from writing numerals as much as possible.

Comment: Ok, sorry about that. I won't anymore on the future. But thanks for your opinion, I appreciate

Comment: You generally don't start a sentence with a numeral, however in the middle of a sentence, the rule used to be spell out from one to ten and then use numerals for anything higher. In any kind of tabular presentation, use numerals exclusively. I think back in those days we used the Stunk and White Elements of Style as our guide. But it was 24 years ago since I last used a style guide, so I might be mistaken on which one it was.

Comment: What's the exact sentence in essence? I'd lean toward "Once a week."

Comment: This is really a Business English Style question, isn't it? I'm not sure that's Workplace asdefined here. (I'm also inclined to say you're overthinking it.)

Comment: My understanding is consistent with what @HLGEM states.  For numbers ten or less use the word, otherwise use numerals.  And avoid starting a sentence with numerals.  So "Fifteen years ago" instead of "15 years ago", even though 15 is larger than ten.

Comment: To tell you the truth if they are going to reject your CV over this - then perhaps look at the rest of the CV

Answer (score 2):

It's a CV so it's a formal document. Write out the number if it's a short one. Some conventions it's one to ten, others it's one to one hundred. And things like two hundred, two thousand, ten million etc,.